# Printing a Hexadecimal array in ascii form

Tags: c, gcc, bitwise-operators

I am having an byte array in my c program

`unsigned char global_buffer[5]={0x0A,0x21,0x01,0x01,0x01};`

When I try to print this array in hyper terminal it displays in ASCII format so its printing in unknown character format.How can i print it as

```
A,21,1,1,1
```

so that the array must be something like this {'A','21','1','1','1'} .

How can i accomplish this using bit shifting?since am working on microcontroller can use %X etc

Comment: Please note that is no such thing as a "hexadecimal array" of type `unsigned char` in C. It's all just numbers, they don't "become" hex until someone chooses to format them as such when converting to string for display purposes.

Comment: If all are store as 0x0A then how can you distinguish between character A and hexadecimal A to print?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use `"%X"` in the `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char global_buffer[5]={0x0A,0x21,0x01,0x01,0x01};

main()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
       printf("%X, ", global_buffer[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Am trying this in a microcontroller it passes the value to USART Transmit i cant format it using %X. So How can convert it to ascii form? The array must be something like this {'A','21','1','1','1'}

Comment: '21' is not **a** byte/char

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Note: `'A'` and `'21'` are _both_ `int` literals.  'A'` certainly will fit in a `char`, while the legal, but unusual, `'21'` will not.  +1 Your `"%X"` is the right way to go (except needs `','`).

Comment: @chux Yes, I know. I mean the "char" in "character" since I have also said "byte"

Answer (score 0):

Use the %x and %X for printing hexadecimal values.
consider the example

```
int hex = 0X0A;
printf("%x\n",hex);  o/p a //for small letters
printf("%X" , hex); o/p A // for capital letters
```